# How to calculate long long / int

Tags: c

I am trying to learn how to code by myself and is experiencing some difficulty in calculations. Can someone please explain why the `pf` always return `0` in the below?

```
int main(void)
{
    //solicit input from users
    long long int num = get_long_long("Credit card no: ");
    eprintf("%lld\n",num);
    //initialize
    int i =0;
    int j =0;
    int counter =0;
    string status;

    //find length of input
    while (num>0)
    {
        num/= 10;
        counter++;
    }
    printf("counter is %i\n",counter);

  //Identify card type by prefix
    int power=(counter-2);
    eprintf("power is %i\n", power);

    int dp = pow(10,power);
    eprintf("divofp is %i\n", dp);
    //prefix=num
    long long int pf=(num/dp);
    eprintf("pf is %lld\n",pf); 
}
```

Comment: Did  you debug the code? You will have `num =0` when `pf = (num/dp);` is executed. That's why you have zero in `pf`.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pf` will always be zero, because `num` is set to zero at the end of your `while` loop.

Therefore `num/anything` will always equal zero.

A good method of debugging, is to step through the code line by line, and look at the values of your variables at each point in time.
This can help you narrow down problems like this.

Comment: Got it now!!! thanks so much for helping

Answer (score 1):

The problem is where you get the length of your number:

```
while (num>0)
    num/=10;
```

num will always be 0 after this and thus your final expression will result in 0 because 0/x = 0 (x != 0).